# Automapper 6.0.2.0, Mapper.Map() throws StackOverflow when mapping Child Entities

Tags: c#, automapper, stack-overflow, automapper-6

Getting straight to the point, I've got the following Models:

```
public abstract class ControlData
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedById")]
    public Collaborator CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UpdatedById")]
    public Collaborator UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

[Table("My_Position_Table")]
public class Position : ControlData
{
    [Key]
    [Column("PositionId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("PositionStatusId")]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StatusId")]
    public PositionStatus Status { get; set; }
    public int OpportunityId { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("OpportunityId")]
    public Opportunity Opportunity { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    [Column("PositionDurationId")]
    public int DurationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DurationId")]
    public PositionDuration Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    //TODO Agregar las otras propiedades con sus respectivos catalogos
    public string PracticeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PracticeId")]
    public Practice Practice { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public PersonRole Role { get; set; }
    public int PlatformId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PlatformId")]
    public Platform Platform { get; set; }
    public int LevelId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LevelId")]
    public Level Level { get; set; }
    public int EnglishLevelId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EnglishLevelId")]
    public EnglishLevel EnglishLevel { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LocationId")]
    public Location Location { get; set; }
    public int? OfficeId { get; set; }
    public int OperationId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OperationId")]
    public Person Operation { get; set; }
    public int? EvaluatorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EvaluatorId")]
    public Collaborator Evaluator { get; set; }
    public int? SourcerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SourcerId")]
    public Collaborator Sourcer { get; set; }
    public List<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
    public int? PositionCancellationReasonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PositionCancellationReasonId")]
    public PositionCancellationReason CancellationReason { get; set; }
    public string CancellationComments { get; set; }
    public int? CancellationById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CancellationById")]
    public Collaborator CancellationBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CancellationDate { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public bool WhereAvailable { get; set; }
    public bool RequestAsset { get; set; }
    public string CityZone { get; set; }
    public string TravelsTo { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SpecificationFile { get; set; }
    public int PositionPriorityId { get; set; }
    public int? SourcingGroupId { get; set; }
}

[Table("My_Opportunity_Table")]
public class Opportunity : ControlData
{
    [Column("OpportunityId")]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("OpportunityStatusId")]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StatusId")]
    public OpportunityStatus Status { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public string MarketId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MarketId")]
    public Market Market { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Column("OpportunityTypeId")]
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TypeId")]
    public OpportunityType Type { get; set; }
    [Column("OpportunityPriorityId")]
    public int PriorityId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PriorityId")]
    public OpportunityPriority Priority { get; set; }
    public int? OpportunityCancellationReasonId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OpportunityCancellationReasonId")]
    public OpportunityCancellationReason CancellationReason { get; set; }
    public string CancellationComments { get; set; }
    public int? CancellationById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CancellationById")]
    public Collaborator CancellationBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CancellationDate { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }        
    public List<OpportunityRole> OpportunityRoles { get; set; }
    public List<Position> Positions { get; set; }

}
```

And also, I've got their equivalents in DTO's:

```
public abstract class ControlDataDTO
{

    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public CollaboratorPlainDTO CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public int? UpdatedById { get; set; }
    public CollaboratorPlainDTO UpdatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class PositionDTO: ControlDataDTO
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public PositionStatusDTO Status { get; set; }
    public int OpportunityId { get; set; }
    public OpportunityDTO Opportunity { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int DurationId { get; set; }
    public PositionDurationDTO Duration { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string PracticeId { get; set; }
    public PracticeDTO Practice { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public PersonRoleDTO Role { get; set; }
    public int PlatformId { get; set; }
    public PlatformDTO Platform { get; set; }
    public int LevelId { get; set; }
    public LevelDTO Level { get; set; }
    public int EnglishLevelId { get; set; }
    public EnglishLevelDTO EnglishLevel { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public LocationDTO Location { get; set; }
    public int? OfficeId { get; set; }
    public int OperationId { get; set; }
    public PersonDTO Operation { get; set; }
    public string OperationIS { get; set; }
    public bool WhereAvailable { get; set; }
    public bool RequestAsset { get; set; }
    public string CityZone { get; set; }
    public string TravelsTo { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CandidatesAccepted { get; set; }
    public int CandidatesRejected { get; set; }
    public int CandidatesWaiting { get; set; }
    public bool HasCandidatesWaiting { get; set; }
    public int TotalCandidates { get; set; }
    public string SpecificationFile { get; set; }
    public int? EvaluatorId { get; set; }
    public int? SourcerId { get; set; }
    public CollaboratorDTO Sourcer { get; set; }
    public int? SourcingGroupId { get; set; }
    public PositionCancellationReasonDTO CancellationReason { get; set; }
}

public class OpportunityDTO: ControlDataDTO
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public OpportunityStatusDTO Status { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public ProjectDTO Project { get; set; }
    public string MarketId { get; set; }
    public MarketDTO Market { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
    public CustomerDTO Customer { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public OpportunityTypeDTO Type { get; set; }
    public int PriorityId { get; set; }
    public OpportunityPriorityDTO Priority { get; set; }
    public int? OpportunityCancellationReasonId { get; set; }
    public OpportunityCancellationReasonDTO CancellationReason { get; set; }
    public string CancellationComments { get; set; }
    public int? CancellationById { get; set; }
    public CollaboratorPlainDTO CancellationBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CancellationDate { get; set; }
    public CollaboratorDTO Responsible { get; set; }
    public List<OpportunityRoleDTO> OpportunityRoles { get; set; }
    public int TotalPositions { get; set; }
    public bool CandidatesWarning { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public List<PositionDTO> Positions { get; set; }
}
```

For this mapping initialization we are using Profiles, like this way:

```
public class AutoMapperConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            // ...
            cfg.AddProfile<OpportunityMappingProfile>();
            // ...
        });
    }
}

public class OpportunityMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public OpportunityMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Opportunity, OpportunityDTO>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Responsible, x => x.MapFrom(c => GetFromOpportunityRoles(c.OpportunityRoles, Constants.OpportunityResponsible)))
            .ForMember(x => x.TotalPositions, x => x.MapFrom(c => c.Positions.Count()))
            .ForMember(x => x.CandidatesWarning, x => x.MapFrom(c => c.Positions.Count() > 0 ? 
                c.Positions.Any(pos => pos.Candidates.Any(cand => cand.StatusId == 3)) : 
                false))
            .ForMember(x => x.CreatedBy, x => x.MapFrom(c => Mapper.Map<CollaboratorPlainDTO>(c.CreatedBy)))
            .ForMember(x => x.UpdatedBy, x => x.MapFrom(c => Mapper.Map<CollaboratorPlainDTO>(c.UpdatedBy)))
            .ForMember(x => x.Positions, x => x.MapFrom(c => Mapper.Map<List<PositionDTO>>(c.Positions))).PreserveReferences(); --> Even using this method, StackOverflow exception is still occurring...
        CreateMap<OpportunityDTO, Opportunity>()
            .ForMember(x => x.CancellationReason, x => x.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.CreatedBy, x => x.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.UpdatedBy, x => x.Ignore())
            .ForMember(x => x.Positions, x => x.Ignore());
    }

    private Collaborator GetFromOpportunityRoles(List<OpportunityRole> opportunityRoles, string rol)
    {
        var opportunityRole = opportunityRoles.FirstOrDefault(opp => opp.ProjectRoleTypeId == rol);
        return opportunityRoles != null ? opportunityRole.Collaborator : null;
    }
}
```

And finally, the logic that does the mapping where I'm getting the commented error...

```
public class OpportunityLogic : IOpportunityLogic
{
    // Properties...

    public OpportunityLogic(parameters list here, though irrelevant for this example)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public ActionResponse<List<OpportunityDTO>> GetOpportunitiesWithPositions(int personId)
    {
        // Information is retrieved from DB, here...
        List<Opportunity> listOpportunities = opportunityRepository.Get(                
            opp => opp.Status,
            opp => opp.Market,
            opp => opp.Customer,
            opp => opp.Type,
            opp => opp.Project,
            opp => opp.Status,
            opp => opp.Positions,
            opp => opp.Positions.Select(pos => pos.Candidates),
            opp => opp.Positions.Select(pos => pos.Status),
            opp => opp.Positions.Select(pos => pos.Practice),
            opp => opp.Positions.Select(pos => pos.Role),
            opp => opp.Positions.Select(pos => pos.Platform),
            opp => opp.Positions.Select(pos => pos.Sourcer));

        // After having retrieved data, here I re-define my model.
        listOpportunities = listOpportunities
            .Where( opp => opp.StatusId == (int)Constants.OpportunityStatus.Open &&
                           opp.Active == true &&
                           opp.Positions.Any(pos => pos.StatusId == (int)Constants.PositionStatus.Open &&
                                                    pos.Candidates.Any(can => can.PersonId == personId &&
                                                                              can.Active == true &&
                                                                              (can.StatusId == (int)Constants.CandidateStatus.Lead || 
                                                                               can.StatusId == (int)Constants.CandidateStatus.Waiting))))
            .ToList();

        // MY PROBLEM IS HERE....
        var mappedOpportunities = Mapper.Map<List<OpportunityDTO>>(listOpportunities);            

        return new ActionResponse<List<OpportunityDTO>> (mappedOpportunities);

    }
}
```

My problem starts when trying to map my Model (*List*)  to the DTO (*List*); the error is the well-known "*StackOverflow Exception*". If I'm using the "**PreserveReferences()**" method, why is still throwing the same exception?. The same goes for "**MaxDepth()** method", after having tried different depth levels (1,2,3...).

I've spent too many hours trying to solve this issue and to be honest, I'm out of ideas already. If anyone has an idea what to do here, I'll be really grateful. 
Thanks and advance & regards!!

Comment: It seems to me you could assist your cause by sharpening this code down the the minimum that demonstrates the problem. Read about providing a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that I was missing ***another Mapping Profile*** that needed to preserve its references, but had not mentioned here, since I was missing that part and that was the one that had causing me all the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 6.1.0 PreserveReferences is set automatically at config time whenever the recursion can be detected statically. If that doesn't happen in your case, open an issue with a full repro and we'll look into it.

http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#circular-references

But you have to remove the Map calls inside the MapFroms. Those ForMember-s are not needed.

Comment: Indeed Lucian, Those members are not needed. So I must get rid of them. The issue here is that I was missing another Mapping Profile that needed to preserve its references, but had not mentioned here, since I was missing that part and that was the one that had causing me all the issues. But thank so much for your support!!