# Automapper mappings tree

Tags: automapper, stack-overflow, circular-reference

Is there any way to list out all automapper mapping expression trees that have been configured in an application.

The reason being we are seeing few edge cases causing stackoverflow exception during mapping objects and want to see if there is any way to look at all the mapping trees. This could possibly point to any circular references.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48892615/automapper-6-0-2-0-mapper-map-throws-stackoverflow-when-mapping-child-entitie/48892873#48892873

Comment: thank you for the link but that doesnt answer my question. I was trying to find a way to review all the mappings defined in a application to look for possible circular references.

Comment: OK, so you prefer having SO exceptions. I understand :)

Comment: I think you didnt understand the question correctly. Thanks for trying.

Comment: No, I just I think it's the wrong question. The way to detect circular references is to look at your types. But that should not be needed because AM already does that for you in the latest versions.

Comment: As I mentioned you didnt understand the question.

Comment: I guess nobody did :)

Comment: automapper doesnt support this out of the box.